# Extract value using regex when space is missing

Tags: regex, tcl, extract

I am trying to extract the text and the third column from the below output. My problem is that there is one line where the space is missing. Is it possible to extract that value in this case?

```
4086   process-working          841901      841901      1234        22
4297   procesor_stats_controller_fmm543182      543182      0           22
4028   ipv6_ma                  3063025     3063025     -55         78
4280   tty-verifyd              694043      694043      0           22
```

My regex so far looks like this:

```
 \d+\s+(\w+-?\w+)\s*\d+\s+\d+\s+(-?\d+)\s+\d+
```

Thank you

EDIT: it's actually a bug in the device, at least one space should be there, so I'll just let them fix it and then retry. Thank you for taking the time to answer this :)

Comment: If you add an line start, line end anchor to either end this works for your sample examples. So: `^\d+\s+(\w+-?\w+)\s*\d+\s+\d+\s+(-?\d+)\s+\d+$` but you also have to have the multiline option on. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Also if you want this all to be one line `\s` is not the right character class.

Comment: It doesn't work like that, I tried it and it extracts the text with some of the numerical value also. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I this case, I'd first split the line into fields

```
foreach line $lines {
    set fields [regexp -inline -all {\S+} $line]
    if {[llength $fields] == 6} {
        puts [lindex $fields 2]
    } else {
        # extract the digits at the end of this field
        regexp {\d+$} [lindex $fields 1] value
        puts $value
    }
}
```

```
841901
543182
3063025
694043
```

Comment: I am actually looking to get the text in the output (the processes), but this would work, yes. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps `regexp {(.*?)(\d+)$} [lindex $fields 1] -> text digits`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `\w`. `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.
So, it'll match with the number also (since space is missing).

Instead of `\w`, use `[a-zA-Z_]`. Hence, this regular expression should do for you  :

```
\d+\s+([a-z]+-?[a-z]+)\s*(\d+)\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+
```

Comment: I have some processes that have [0-9] in them so this solution won't work. Thank you :)

Comment: Okay. Have you any considerations regarding what length the second and/or third column!!

Comment: I can't really put a limit to that cause I don't know if I don't have any processes that are even longer than that. It's a good idea though.